# XPages Checkbox Group not working with Bootstrap Theme?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, xpages, xpages-extlib

I am having trouble with the "Check Box Group" XPages control when using a Boostrap Theme with version "9.0.1.v00_10_20141105-0922" of the extension library. The values of the item bound to a check box group are not saved when I use the "Bootstrap3.2.0" or "Bootstrap3.2.0_flat" theme (or any theme that extends these themes).

Here is a very simple XPage to demonstrate the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:this.data>
        <xp:dominoDocument var="doc" formName="document"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:label value="Subject" id="labelSubject" for="inputTextSubject"></xp:label>
    <xp:inputText value="#{doc.Subject}" id="inputTextSubject">
    </xp:inputText>
    <xp:label value="Categories" id="labelCategories"></xp:label>
    <xp:checkBoxGroup id="checkBoxGroupCategories" value="#{doc.Categories}"
        layout="lineDirection">
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="cat1"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="cat2"></xp:selectItem>
        <xp:selectItem itemLabel="cat3"></xp:selectItem>
    </xp:checkBoxGroup>
    <xp:button value="Submit" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete" immediate="false" save="true" id="eventHandler1">
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

The database has a form with just two fields:

- Subject, single value text field
- Categories, multi-value field (checkbox)

If I use any other theme the values are saved, swiching back to one of the Bootstrap themes prevents the value(s) from being saved. In that case not even the "Categories" item is created in the document.

For the check box control it is irrelevant whether the items just have the itemLabel attribute or also an itemValue and it also makes no difference whether I am using a fixed or a computed set of values.

It also makes no difference whether or not the Application Layout control is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue in release 10, around data in CheckBox groups being lost. It was logged as SPR #LHEY9QHH58. It was fixed in release 11, this entry is in the change log inside the readme of R11:

`LHEY9QHH58_901_N_extlib_responsive checkbox group not persisting data`

As Howard suggested, you should upgrade to the latest version of the Extension Library. Release 12 was posted last week on OpenNTF.

Comment: Thanks, Brian. That will hopefully help to convince the customer to upgrade to v12.

Answer (score 1):

Just copied your source into an XPage and tried it with the Bootstrap3.2.0 theme. It saved the values fine. I am using the latest extension library from last week. Maybe try this new release?

Field Name: categories
Data Type: Text
Data Length: 4 bytes
Seq Num: 1
Dup Item ID: 0
Field Flags: SUMMARY

"cat2"

Howard